# Python Interactive mode on Arch Linux "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: python, arch-linux, segmentation-fault

Using Arch Linux everytime I try to use Python interactive mode no matter what I type I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and the Python interpreter exits.

I do not have any problem running Python scripts or doing something like:

```
$ echo "print(1+1)" | python
```

But when I enter interactive mode, whether it is with `python` or `python2`, as soon as I type any command and press enter, the interpreter halts and then if I press enter again (or any other key) I get the message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and the interpreter exits.

I test installing [bpython](https://bpython-interpreter.org/) and I have no problem or errors with this interface for the python interpreter.

I tried `gdb` and when I type `run` at the `gdb` prompt I had to press enter twice (when hit enter once it just halted) and then got:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/python
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and `gdb` exits.

Maybe this information is useful:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2

$ python --version
Python 3.6.1

$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.13

$ uname -a
Linux archimiro 4.11.6-3-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 22 12:21:46 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you run it under `gdb` and perhaps get a `bt` ?

Comment: @thrig Thanks! I would love to do that but I'm not sure how. I read about that when I searched for my problem and ran `gdb python` and got `(gdb)`, but was not sure what to do after that, so I tried typing a python command and then `bt` and got `No stack`, and then came here :).

Comment: `run` at the `gdb` prompt should start `python` and dump you into interactive mode.

Comment: @thrig At the `gdb` prompt I typed `run` and got this output `Starting program: /usr/bin/python 

Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and gdb exits.

Comment: I do not know if it's worth mentioning but after I typed `run` and pressed `enter` nothing happened, so I pressed enter again and got the message `Starting program: /usr/bin/python Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and then `gdb` exits. That is also what happen when I try to run a command in Python interactive mode, I have to press enter twice and then I get the message and the python shell exits.

Comment: Hmm, seriously hosed. Have you done any Major version updates of python on this system (so that there might be old software from a previous version the new install might be loading)?

Comment: @thrig Not that I am aware off, just the usual `sudo pacman -Syu` and when I noticed the problem I ran `sudo pacman -Syu python python2`.

Comment: I'm almost certain that you broke one of `python`'s dependencies but finding which one can be a bit tough.  I can hardly believe that you would not get anything more out of `gdb`.  You should at least try running `gdb -c core pythoncommand` to see where it crashed.

Comment: You might get a clue from `strace python`, compared with the non-interactive version.

Comment: @meuh I can't thank you enough for that tip. I ran Python with `strace` and notice that it was loading my `~/.inputrc`which was not loaded when non-interactive, so I remove it and it works! Now I have to figure out what was messing it since interactive Python uses readline and I had a lot of things in my `.inputrc`. If you want to post your suggestion as an answer I'll be glad to mark it as the accepted answer and vote it up, and I'll post as soon as I know what was in my `.inputrc` that mess up the interactive Python.

Comment: I think it would be much better if you post the answer, especially if you manage to find what lines are causing the problem, as I'm sure other people are likely to see the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) suggestion I ran Python with `strace` and look at the differences between interactive and non-interactive Python.

Interactive Python read my `~/.inputrc` as it uses [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), and this was the file that was causing the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I had an `~/.inputrc` which came from another machine (Ubuntu) and inside of it I had blindly copied the contents of (Ubuntu) `/usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows`.

The content of `/usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows` is:

```
# This file controls the behaviour of line input editing for
# programs that use the Gnu Readline library.
#
# Arrow keys in keypad mode
#
"\C-[OD"        backward-char
"\C-[OC"        forward-char
"\C-[OA"        previous-history
"\C-[OB"        next-history
#
# Arrow keys in ANSI mode
#
"\C-[[D"        backward-char
"\C-[[C"        forward-char
"\C-[[A"        previous-history
"\C-[[B"        next-history
#
# Arrow keys in 8 bit keypad mode
#
"\C-M-OD"       backward-char
"\C-M-OC"       forward-char
"\C-M-OA"       previous-history
"\C-M-OB"       next-history
#
# Arrow keys in 8 bit ANSI mode
#
"\C-M-[D"       backward-char
"\C-M-[C"       forward-char
"\C-M-[A"       previous-history
"\C-M-[B"       next-history
```

The `8 bit keypad mode` and the `8 bit ANSI mode` were the specific cause of the problem so after removing them everything works fine.

Thanks to [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig) for pointing me to `gdb` and being patient enough as I had never used that tool before. The same with [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) who suggested using `strace` which was also new to me. I had no idea where to start debugging as I am just a casual user who enjoys learning new things. Great community!